# Создание прокручивающегося div на js со скроллБаром

Tags: javascript

Создаю динамическую таблицу. Чтобы она очень далеко не двигала вниз футер хочу блок, в которой она находиться, сделать фиксированных размеров. И при превышении размеров чтобы появлялся скроллБар и он прокручивался в низ. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: `max-height:500px; overflow:scroll;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установите блоку максимальную высоту и включите прокрутку:

```
.table-div {
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Для справки:

[owerflow](http://htmlbook.ru/CSS/overflow) [max-height](http://htmlbook.ru/css/max-height)